# Convert partial H:M:S durations with missing parts, to Seconds; or Right-align non-NA data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, timedelta

TL;DR: I want to right-align this df, overwriting NaN's/shifting them to the left:

```py
In [6]: series.str.split(':', expand=True)
Out[6]:
        0       1       2
0       1  25.842    <NA>
1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
2       0  15.413    <NA>
3  54.154    <NA>    <NA>
4       3       2  06.284
```

to get it as continuous data with the right-most columns filled:

```
        0       1       2
0       0       1  25.842  # 0 or NA
1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  # this NA should remain
2       0       0  15.413
3       0       0  54.154
4       3       2  06.284
```

#### What I'm actually trying to do:

I've got a Pandas Series of Durations/timedeltas which are *roughly* in an H:M:S format - but sometimes the 'H' or the 'H:M' parts can be missing - so I can't just pass it onto `Timedelta` or `datetime`. What I want to do is **convert them to seconds, which I've done** but it seems a bit convoluted:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: series = pd.Series(['1:25.842', pd.NA, '0:15.413', '54.154', '3:2:06.284'], dtype='string')
   ...: t = series.str.split(':')  # not using `expand` helps for the next step
   ...: t
Out[1]:
0       [1, 25.842]
1              <NA>
2       [0, 15.413]
3          [54.154]
4    [3, 2, 06.284]
dtype: object

In [2]: # reverse it so seconds are first; and NA's are just empty
   ...: rows = [i[::-1] if i is not pd.NA else [] for i in t]

In [3]: smh = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows).astype('float')
   ...: # left-aligned is okay since it's continuous Secs->Mins->Hrs
   ...: smh
Out[3]:
        0    1    2
0  25.842  1.0  NaN
1     NaN  NaN  NaN
2  15.413  0.0  NaN
3  54.154  NaN  NaN
4   6.284  2.0  3.0
```

If I don't do this `fillna(0)` step then it generates NaN's for the seconds-conversion later.

```py
In [4]: smh.iloc[:, 1:] = smh.iloc[:, 1:].fillna(0)  # NaN's in first col = NaN from data; so leave
   ...: # convert to seconds
   ...: smh.iloc[:, 0] + smh.iloc[:, 1] * 60 + smh.iloc[:, 2] * 3600
Out[4]:
0       85.842
1          NaN
2       15.413
3       54.154
4    10926.284
dtype: float64
```

^ Expected end result.

(Alternatively, I could write a small Python-only function to split on `:`'s and then convert based on how many values each list has.)

Comment: To future visitors: See the [performance of the various solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483372/1431750) in my answer below. The _Accepted answer_ is more robust wrt splitting into 2 columns or 3 columns based on the full input series; so those checks need to be added to the other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attack the problem earlier by padding `series` with `'0:'` as follows:

```
# setup
series = pd.Series(['1:25.842', pd.NA, '0:15.413', '54.154', '3:2:06.284'], dtype='string')

# create a padding of 0 series
counts = 2 - series.str.count(':')
pad = pd.Series(['0:' * c if pd.notna(c) and c > 0 else '' for c in counts], dtype='string')

# apply padding
res = pad.str.cat(series)

t = res.str.split(':', expand=True)
print(t)
```

**Output**

```
      0     1       2
0     0     1  25.842
1  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
2     0     0  15.413
3     0     0  54.154
4     3     2  06.284
```

Comment: Padding beforehand /facepalm. Yeah, that would've been quicker and straightforward.

Comment: Btw, the `and c > 0` part can be skipped since `'abc' * 0 == ''`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with `numpy` to right align the dataframe, the basic idea is to `sort` the dataframe along `axis=1` so that the `NaN` values appear before the `non-NaN` values while also keeping the order of `non-NaN` values intact:

```
i = np.argsort(np.where(df.isna(), -1, 0), 1)
df[:] = np.take_along_axis(df.values, i, axis=1)


     0    1       2
0  NaN  1.0  25.842
1  NaN  NaN     NaN
2  NaN  0.0  15.413
3  NaN  NaN  54.154
4  3.0  2.0   6.284
```

---

In order to get the `total seconds` you can multiply the right aligned dataframe by `[3600, 60, 1]` and take `sum` along `axis=1`:

```
df.mul([3600, 60, 1]).sum(1)

0       85.842
1        0.000
2       15.413
3       54.154
4    10926.284
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for adding in the `[3600, 60, 1]` multiplication - that's what I initially wanted to do with the right-aligned df. (Except that I need to replace all the 0's back to NaN's.)

Comment: @aneroid No problem. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Using the ***sorting NA's*** approach [in Shubham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481371/1431750), I've come up with this - Utilise Pandas `apply` and Python `sorted` :

```py
series = pd.Series(['1:25.842', pd.NA, '0:15.413', '54.154', '3:2:06.284'], dtype='string')
df = series.str.split(':', expand=True)

# key for sorted is `pd.notna`, so False(0) sorts before True(1)
df.apply(sorted, axis=1, key=pd.notna, result_type='broadcast')
```

(And then multiply as needed.) But it's quite slow, see below.

**2.** By **pre-padding the '0:'s** [in Dani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481483/1431750), I can then create `pd.Timedelta`'s directly and get their `total_seconds`:

```py
res = ...  # from answer

pd.to_timedelta(res, errors='coerce').map(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
```

(But doing the expand-split and then multiply+sum is faster across ~10k rows.)

---

**Performance caveats**, with 10k rows of data:

Initial code/attempt in my question, row reversal - so maybe I'll stick with it:

```py
%%timeit
t = series.str.split(':')
rows = [i[::-1] if i is not pd.NA else [] for i in t]
smh = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows).astype('float')
smh.mul([1, 60, 3600]).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)

# 14.3 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Numpy `argsort` + `take_along_axis`:

```py
%%timeit
df = series.str.split(':', expand=True)
i = np.argsort(np.where(df.isna(), -1, 0), 1)
df[:] = np.take_along_axis(df.values, i, axis=1)
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mul([3600, 60, 1]).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)

# 30.1 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Padding beforehand:

```py
%%timeit
counts = 2 - series.str.count(':')
pad = pd.Series(['0:' * c if pd.notna(c) else '' for c in counts], dtype='string')
res = pad.str.cat(series)
t = res.str.split(':', expand=True)
t.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mul([3600, 60, 1]).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)

# 48.3 ms ± 607 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Padding beforehand, timedeltas + total_seconds:

```py
%%timeit
counts = 2 - series.str.count(':')
pad = pd.Series(['0:' * c if pd.notna(c) else '' for c in counts], dtype='string')
res = pad.str.cat(series)

pd.to_timedelta(res, errors='coerce').map(lambda x: x.total_seconds())

# 183 ms ± 9.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Pandas `apply` + Python `sorted` (very slow):

```py
%%timeit
df = series.str.split(':', expand=True)
df = df.apply(sorted, axis=1, key=pd.notna, result_type='broadcast')
df.apply(pd.to_numeric).mul([3600, 60, 1]).sum(axis=1, min_count=1)

# 1.4 s ± 36.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```